# su: User not known to the underlying authentication module

Tags: ubuntu, su, useradd

I created a new user in linux by running `useradd` command:

```
david@machineA:~> sudo useradd golden
david@machineA:~> sudo su - golden
Creating directory '/home/golden'.
$ ^C
$ exit
su: User not known to the underlying authentication module
```

But when I try to switch to that user, I am seeing an error: `su: User not known to the underlying authentication module`

What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useradd` program doesn't add a password entry automatically, whereas `adduser` prompts for directory information (name, phone, office etc) as well as prompts to set a password for your newly created user.

Comment: ok so what I should do now? How can I fix it.. same command worked fine on some other box few months back but now it doesnt work on this new box.

Comment: Delete the user (`deluser golden`) and then re-create using `adduser golden`

Comment: yeah now it works. I have another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364296/getting-permission-denied-error-while-creating-ssh-directory-through-ssh-keygen) related to this I guess.